# How do you get an access token from azure active directory (V2) to allow access to Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureservicebus, microsoft-identity-platform

I've been following the this tutoral to get an access token for azure service bus so that I can post messages to a queue using Postman:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-tokenTh

Following the example through works and I can get an access token.  However, the example uses the older v1 token endpoints eg

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tennant-id}}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btennant-id%7D%7D/oauth2/token)

I want to use the current v2 endpoint  eg

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tennant-id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btennant-id%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

But when I switch get this error:

```
AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://servicebus.azure.net is not valid.
```

I'm assuming that the name of the scope must have changed and I cannot find any documentation about what scopes are for azure services.  I've tried a bunch of things such as https://servicebus.windows.net
and https://myqueue.servicebus.windows.net and googling but I've found nothing.

### Update

Following on from the answers provided I have appended ".default" to the requested scope.  This hasn't solved to the problem but has changed the error message  I now get Error: invalid_client in the postman console.

I'm trying with the postman "get new access token" feature and have set it like this

[[image: Postman screensshot1]

### Update 2

Grant type was wrong in the last update - should be client credentials then it will work.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: @JoyWang I've not got it working yet but updated the question with the progress. I'm trying to find documentation for ".default" to see if it needs other roles assigning to the service principle beyond the ones covered in that article.

Comment: From the screenshot, the `Grant Type` is `Authorization Code`, it is the auth code flow, in the doc you referred to, it uses the client credential flow, you need to change it to `Client credentials`.

Comment: uurgh - thanks @JoyWang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `v2.0` endpoint of the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), you need to [use `scope` instead of `resource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#scopes-not-resources) in the request body, and pass the [`/.default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope) to the url, it should be `https://servicebus.azure.net/.default`.

**Sample:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mostly you might have missed to add .default in the scope parameter. Please try appending .default that is `https://servicebus.azure.net/.default` for scope parameter value.

Comment: Hi this is the right answer, Thank you for giving it! I've accepted Joy Wang's as it contains screenshots and links which others may find more useful when googling.

Comment: @Twisted ,Thanks for mentioning that.